# SQL find and replace part of a column

Tags: sql, join, replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 tables and I was wondering how to replace part of a column in table 1 with a value from table 2 in SQL?

I want to find value "Field1" within Region2 and replace it with "Field2":

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Expected result would look like this:

| Region2 | Region3 |
| --- | --- |
| USA | USA_L5 |
| CANADA | CANADA_L5 |

It is not only replacing with blanks, as well parts which would be hard to do with regex.

If you have any ideas how this can be achieved please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example data:

```
create table #regions
(
    Region2 varchar(100),
    Region3 varchar(100)
)

create table #lookups
(
    Record int,
    Field1 varchar(100),
    Field2 varchar(100)
)

insert into #regions values
('USA_L6','USA_L5'),
('CANADA_L6','CANADA_L5')

insert into #lookups values
(26,'Central_America','Central America'),
(27,'_L7',null),
(28,'_L6',null),
(29,'_L5',null),
(30,'_L4',null),
(31,'_L3',null),
(32,'_L2',null)
```

This query gives the desired output:

```
select
    replace(r.Region2,isnull(l.Field1,''),isnull(l.Field2,'')) as Region2,
    r.Region3
from #regions r
left join #lookups l on r.Region2 like '%' + isnull(l.Field1,'') + '%'
```

Results:

| Region2 | Region3 |
| --- | --- |
| USA | USA_L5 |
| CANADA | CANADA_L5 |

This makes some assumptions about there being a maximum of one match in `#lookups.Field1` for each value in `#regions.Region2`, but your question and examples don't give any indication that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    replace(t1.region2, IFNULL( t2.field1,''), IFNULL(t2.field2, '') ) as region2
    , t1.region3
from table1 as t1 
join table2 t2  on concat('_',split_part(t1.region2,'_',2) )   = t2.field1
```